# FORTRAN-OpenMP. Parallel Do-loop not working efficiently

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I made a calculation of the differential cross section of coins using a simple Monte Carlo method.
Because one of the iterations took about 4 minutes I wondered if it would be faster if I can parallelize one of the `do-loop's`.
The code is the following

```
program Executable
   use nrtype
   use omp_lib

    implicit none

    ! Input Variables
    integer(I4B) :: Iter_max = 6
    integer(I4B) :: coins_max = 5
    real(SP) :: Lx = 10.0
    real(SP) :: Ly = 10.0
    real(SP) :: R = 1.0


    ! Intern variables
    integer(I4B) :: i,m,procs,threads
    real(SP) :: ratio_conv, ratio_dens, density, ratio_flux
    real(SP), dimension(5) :: CS_conv
    real(DP) :: time
    real(SP) :: start, finish


    !Starts the calculation
    time = omp_get_wtime()

    procs = omp_get_num_procs()
    threads = omp_get_max_threads()

    print*, 'Processors', procs
    print*, 'Threads', threads

   !%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CONVERGENCE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    open(1, file = 'Convergencia.dat')


    do i = 1,Iter_max

        ratio_conv = ratio_flux(Lx,Ly,R,i,5)

        density = 5.0/(Lx*Ly)

        CS_conv(i) = ratio_conv/density


        write(1,*) 5**(i-1)*10**5, CS_conv(i)

        if (i > 2) then

            if (abs(CS_conv(i) - CS_conv(i-1)) < (1e-3)*CS_conv(i) .AND. & abs(CS_conv(i) - CS_conv(i-2)) < (1e-3)*CS_conv(i)) then

        print*, 'Convergence achieved at i =',i
                exit

            else if (i == Iter_max) then

                print*, 'Didn't achieve convergence'
                exit
            end if

        end if

    enddo

    close(1)

    call system('gnuplot Convergencia.gnu')

!%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DENSITY CHANGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    open(2, file = 'cociente_flujo_vs_densidad.dat')

    !$OMP PARALLEL default(none) shared(coins_max,Lx,Ly,R,i) private(m,density,flux_dens)

    !$OMP DO
    do m = 1,coins_max

        flux_dens = ratio_flux(Lx,Ly,R,i,m)

        density = m/(Lx*Ly)


        write(2,*) density, flux_dens

        print*, 'Coins', m

    enddo
    !$OMP END DO

    !$OMP END PARALLEL

    close(2)

    time = omp_get_wtime() - time
    print*, 'Time simulation = ',time,' seconds.'


    call cpu_time(start)
    call system('gnuplot CS_pendiente.gnu')
    call CPU_TIME(finish)

    print*, 'Time regression', finish-start, 'seconds.'


end program
```

This basically calls two subroutines which are not running on parallel and caused no problems before. The parallelizable part what it does is to write in a file different values of densities and fluxes of 'particles'. Since they are all independent of each other what I intended to do is that each thread runs the cycle for a different value of `m`.

The problem is the following: when I run the same code without the `!$OMP PARALLEL DO`, I get the correct results but it lasts about 4 to 5 minutes. Now when I add the `!$OMP PARALLEL DO - !$OMP END PARALLEL DO` the code seems to work fine but not in that section. I mean, the first part of the code is done, giving the same result as the non-parallel try I did, but when it reaches the `!$OMP... etc etc` the number of threads in my computer are assigned to the program but it does not calculate anything. In fact the line `print*, 'Coins', m` doesn't show up in console, meaning that the program is not calculating anything at all. The program runs for 10 minutes, my cpu is loaded and unloaded with the task and nothing happens, so I stop the program.

I read in some posts that the problem may be because of the `cpu_time` command but I made sure that the lines for it were outside the parallelizable part of the code. I've also changed `!$OMP PARALLEL DO - !$OMP PARALLEL END DO` to `!$OMP DO - !$OMP END DO` since I've seen both examples but that didn't help neither.

I am using MacOS and Eclipse IDE, and I've added the flag `-fopenmp` to the building and linking preferences of the program.

I've literally don't know what I'm doing wrong and anything would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is probably in the file writing. Just store your results on a large shared array that you write on the file only after exiting the parallel loop.

Comment: @Gilles, just tried that, but didnt work neither.

Comment: Please post version of your code that is a minimal reproducer of your issue, and which we could compile and test. This is [all explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)